# Shrink x-axis to handle null data in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I'm trying to find a way to change the ratio of the x-axis in Grafana when graph data is null

I.e. i have a time frame that has no data i would like the x-axis to shrink during this time and not provide the same real time scale as the time frames that do have data.

[image: Grafana visualization]